# TypeError: 'errors' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

When opening a text file to read, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "compugin.py", line 13, in
>   
>       input = open('chatbot.txt', 'r', errors = 'ignore') TypeError: 'errors' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Here's my code:

```
import nltk
import io
import numpy as np
import random
import string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

## Download needed NLTK packages
## nltk.data.path.append('/usr/local/share/nltk_data')

#### INPUT:
input = open('chatbot.txt', 'r', errors = 'ignore')
rawText = input.read()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the builtin `open` in 2.7 doesn't support an `errors` argument... you might be after `io.open(...)` since you've already imported `io` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are different `open()` functions, and Python is confusing with another one.
Try the following:

```
input = io.open(...
```